# Angular2 DI Error No provider for EventEmitter

Tags: angular, compilation, runtime

I've a issue at runtime when I try to start my Angular2 application:

> EXCEPTION: No provider for EventEmitter!
>
> Error: DI Error
>       at NoProviderError.ZoneAwareError (localhost/js/polyfills.js:4666:33)
>       at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (localhost/js/vendor.js:11730:16)
>       at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (localhost/js/vendor.js:77033:16)
>       at new NoProviderError (localhost/js/vendor.js:77082:16)
>       at ReflectiveInjector_.*throwOrNull (localhost/js/vendor.js:123981:19)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKeyDefault (localhost/js/vendor.js:124018:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.*getByKey (localhost/js/vendor.js:123968:25)
>       at ReflectiveInjector*.get (ocalhost/js/vendor.js:123730:21)
>       at AppModuleInjector.get (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:213:131)
>       at AppModuleInjector.getInternal (/AppModule/module.ngfactory.js:688:61)
>       at AppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (localhost/js/vendor.js:77948:44)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.injectorGet (localhost/js/vendor.js:124739:45)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal
>   (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:15:173)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView (localhost/js/vendor.js:124695:21)

But I've no idea where it comes from...

Here is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    // option for momentjs compilation
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "src/custom-typings",
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts",
    "typings/globals/node/index.d.ts",
    "typings/globals/jasmine/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

And I'm using 'awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader' , 'angular2-router-loader'.

Any idea?

Comment: I got something like this, when I switched to a different branch and left the localhost running, when I switched back it started to give this error. I restarted the localhost and It was fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the issue!
Chrome has not showing the good information... Firefox and IE indicate the service that causes the issue SlimLoadingBarService.

Then I've seen that it was registered on github:
https://github.com/akserg/ng2-slim-loading-bar/issues/32

Thanks Günter for editing the post.  How could I made it myself next time?

Comment: Thanks. Ran into a very generic angular issue in Chrome and after seeing this I checked Edge which had the actual details.